# Regular Expression for a Java String Contains contains Alphabet and : /

Tags: java, regex

I have a set of Strings like `"04/21 01:55 P "`, `"1"`, `"10/21"`. I wrote a regex as follows

```
^([[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} P|A ]+)
```

It should accept only the format of Strings like `"04/21 01:55 P "`. But it is also accepting strings like  `"1"`, `"10/21"`

Could any one let me know where I want wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the surrounding `[]` by `()`.

You'll need to change the `P|A` part too, either by `(P|A)` or `[PA]`.

Answer (score 1):

You've put everything in one big character class, which is why single digits are being matched as well. You can try something like

```
^(\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2} (?:P|A) )+
```